# Match keys to values in dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, digraphs

Say for example this is my dictionary:

```
my_dict= {"0" : {"1","2","3"},"1":{"2"},"2":{"3"}}
```

I want to pair these values and keys together in every instance. What would be the most efficient way to add each key, into the corresponding values key to make the pair. Sorry if my wording is overly confusing. Essentially, I want it to become:

```
my_dict={"0" : {"1","2","3"}, "1" : {"0","2"}, "2" : {"0","1","3"}, "3" : {"0","2"}}
```

This way, every number is paired in both key and value form. If it's still unclear what I am asking, just let me know and I will try to explain clearer.

Another way I could try to explain it is imagine my current dictionary as the matchings in a digraph, and I want to convert it to show the matchings in an undirected graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this . Example -

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(set)
for key,value in my_dict.items():
    result[key].update(value)
    for elem in value:
        result[elem].add(key)
```

Here you create a `defaultdict` with values as `set` , then for every key in your original dictionary, update that for the same key in the `result` defaultdict. Then iterating over every element in the value (set) , you add the `key` as the value for the element in the `result` defaultdict.

Demo -

```
>>> my_dict= {"0" : {"1","2","3"},"1":{"2"},"2":{"3"}}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> result = defaultdict(set)
>>> for key,value in my_dict.items():
...     result[key].update(value)
...     for elem in value:
...         result[elem].add(key)
...
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
{'0': {'1', '2', '3'},
 '1': {'2', '0'},
 '2': {'0', '1', '3'},
 '3': {'2', '0'}}
```

Comment: Awesome, that did exactly what I wanted! Is it possible to store this in a regular dict after putting it into a defaultdict? Sorry, still total newbie when it comes to python and programming in general.

Comment: defaultdict is a subclass of dict , you can do everything with a defaultdict that you can do with a normal dict , hence you don't actually need to convert to a normal dict . But if you really really want to , you can simply do dict(result) and you will get a normal dict back.

Comment: Honestly, thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.